# Switch icon mode after a few seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi have the following ajax function. After click on the link the icon should be replaced from "off" to "working" icon, and at the end of the work the icon should replaced to "on".

I want that the icon will be switched back to "off" after a few seconds on "on" status. Can someone show me how to do that? I'm new in Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/work', type: "GET", 
    beforeSend: function (data, jqXHR) {
        $('#status').attr("src", "/img/_working.gif");
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#status').attr("src", "/img/_on.png");
        $("#work").html(data)
        $("#work").show()
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       $('#status').attr("src", "/img/_error.gif");
        alert('error')
    }
});

<img src="/img/_off.png" class="img-swap" id="status" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;"/>
```

Comment: weird to start a file name with `_` ...

Comment: Don't worry. It's just a draft :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#status').attr("src", "/img/_off.png"); }, 3000);
```

Where 3000 is the time delay in milliseconds